# java.lang.IllegalStateException: Configuration error

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

Found that IllegalStateException is used to indicate that "a method has been invoked at an illegal or inappropriate time." Now, while doing JUnit testing I found this error. Any help?
**N.B:** I am beginner in Java Spring Boot Framework. So, solution can be simple one.

**found multiple declarations of @BootstrapWith for test class [com.jrp.pma.controller.HttpRequestTest]: [@org.springframework.test.context.BootstrapWith(value=org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTestContextBootstrapper), @org.springframework.test.context.BootstrapWith(value=org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.DataJpaTestContextBootstrapper)]**

```
package com.jrp.pma.controller;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.DataJpaTest;
import org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTest;
import org.springframework.boot.test.web.client.TestRestTemplate;
import org.springframework.boot.web.server.LocalServerPort;
import org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringRunner;
import static org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.assertEquals;
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)
//@DataJpaTest
public class HttpRequestTest {
  @LocalServerPort
  private int port;
  @Autowired
  private TestRestTemplate restTemplate;
  @Test
  public void homePageReturnsVersionNumberCorrectly_thenSuccess(){
    String renderHtml = this.restTemplate.getForObject("http://localhost:" + port + "/", String.class);
    assertEquals(renderHtml.contains("3.3.3"), false);
  }
}
```

[image]

Comment: why do you need DataJpaTest ?

Comment: `@SpringBootTest` and `@DataJpaTest` (like any other slice actually) are mutually exclusive. Next you are mixing JUnit4 and Junit5 (generally not a good idea).

Comment: @M.Deinum Thank you. Just commented out the DataJpaTest annotation. Now got assertEquals error.